# to display whole close button visible outside modal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display full close button/text while maintaining modal's position:fixed and overflow:scroll if i replace overflow:scroll with overflow:visible it appears fully but stops scrolling modal and modal content.

```
<div id="root_component">
       <div class="modal" >
               <a class="modal-close btn-floating btn-small 
                   waves-effect waves-light right clearfix">
                        <i class="material-icons">cancel</i>
                    </a>
          <div class="modal-content"></div>
     </div>    
</div>



.modal {
        width: 80% !important;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        z-index: 1003;
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
        position: fixed;
        padding: 0;
        margin: auto;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
    #root_component .clearfix {
        position: absolute;
        right: -16px;
        top: -16px;
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

[image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgNWv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why enabling overflow on `.modal`? It seems more appropriate to enable it on `.modal-content` which would fix your issue if i understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You must keep the .modal visible to display the close button. 
And you can put the `overflow: auto` into you content:

```
.modal {
  overflow: visible;
}
.modal-content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```